# How to apply 360 video as a texture in ARKit

Tags: arkit

I've been building a portal in ARKit, and while building out a virtual environment is easy to create and move around in, I would like to make the environment I would be entering a 360 video playing on repeat. I think it can be done by wrapping a 360 video as a texture to a sphere, but ARKit does not seem to have that option. Does anyone know how to do this?

An example of what I'm trying to do can be seen here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO2a7QTTAk4

Comment: ARKit doesn't display anything itself; it works with SceneKit, SpriteKit, Unity, your own custom rendering engine, etc — those are the parts that draw content on the screen, so those are the parts to ask about. Which display technology are you using?

Comment: I'm using SceneKit. I was thinking I could create the texture in SpriteKit, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Here  a sample, I hope this can help you

```swift
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self
    
    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    
    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()
    
    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.isPlaying = true

    // create a texture that will be applied to sphere 

    let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: sceneView.frame.width, height: sceneView.frame.height))
    spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    
    let videoUrl  = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "360videoname", withExtension: "mp4")
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl!)
    
    let videoSpriteKitNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer:videoPlayer)
    videoSpriteKitNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width/2, y: spriteKitScene.size.height/2)
    videoSpriteKitNode.size = spriteKitScene.size
    videoSpriteKitNode.yScale = -1.0
    videoSpriteKitNode.play()
    spriteKitScene.addChild(videoSpriteKitNode)

    // create a sphere and apply the texture
    let sphere = create(stars: SCNSphere(radius:30), and: spriteKitScene, and: nil, and: nil, and: nil, and: SCNVector3(0,0,0))
    
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)

    
}

func create(stars geometry: SCNGeometry, and diffuse: SKScene?, and specular: UIImage?, and emission: UIImage?, and normal: UIImage?, and position: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {
    let node = SCNNode()
    node.geometry = geometry
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = diffuse
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = specular
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.normal.contents = normal
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = emission
    node.position = position
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    
    return node
}
```

Comment: If you want to stream live from a remote url in the above example, point to the remote url...  let videoUrl = NSURL(string:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SamsungInternet/examples/master/360-video/paris-by-diego.mp4")

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 11, SceneKit can display video on any surface if you assign an `AVPlayer` to the corresponding material property's [`contents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents). (This doesn't (yet?) appear in the docs for that property, but was mentioned at WWDC and is noted in the headers.)

If your video content is projected right — aspect ratio 2:1, an [equirectangular or "lat/long" projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) — the 360 video should appear correctly when mapped onto a SceneKit sphere geometry (`SCNSphere`, non-geodesic).

You'll probably also need to set the material's `cullMode` and/or `isDoubleSided` properties to make sure the inside faces of the sphere render when the camera is placed inside it. And you should consider which material property to assign your texture map to so that it interacts correctly with lighting ([`emission`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462527-emission) is probably a good choice if you want to display the video unshaded).